# PySide2 QtCore.Qthread update value emit and connect

Tags: python, qt, qthread, pyside2, qtcore

I have a problem updating a variable with thread! I have the following problem :

> RuntimeWarning: MetaObjectBuilder::addMethod: Invalid method signature
>   provided for "CPU"   self.threadclass.connect(SIGNAL('CPU'),
>   self.updateProgressBar)'

The code is:

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import SIGNAL
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

from view import weicount_main_view
from source import sysinfo


class WeicountMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, weicount_main_view.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WeicountMain, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.start()
        self.threadclass.CPU_VALUE.connect(SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), self.updateProgressBar)

    def updateProgressBar(self, val):
        self.progressBar.setValue(val)

class CpuClass(QtCore.QObject):
    cpu = Signal()

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    CPU_VALUE = CpuClass()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.CPU_VALUE.emit(SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), sysinfo.getCPU())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = WeicountMain()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

sysinfo file:

```
import psutil


def getCPU():
    return psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
```

Comment: Where do you declare the `CPU` signal?

Comment: 1) add `CPU = Signal()` before `def __init__(self, parent=None):`, 2) change  `self.CPU.emit(sysinfo.getCPU())`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. If I define the CPU variable as Signal () before the init within the Qthread class, the emit function does not find the reference to the function.
To solve this problem I created a QObject class with the CPU variable as Signal () inside it, so inside the Qthread class before the init I inserted another variable with the call to the object class. now the emit function is available but when I go to run it is suggested to me:
` in run self.CPU_VALUE.emit (sysinfo.getCPU ()) - TypeError: Use the function PySide2.QtCore.SIGNAL on signals `

Comment: I changed the code, inserting the created object class and edit emit args.
But the problem is always the same

Comment: RuntimeWarning: MetaObjectBuilder::addMethod: Invalid method signature provided for "CPU_VALUE"
  self.threadclass.CPU_VALUE.connect(SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), self.updateProgressBarExample)

Comment: Now, how can I dynamically pass a value? Are there other methods to create a multiprocess system with PySide2 to pass values between distinct processes?